Can you `std::move` the `.data()` of a `std::vector`?
This question comes from problems with an API that wants a std::vector<uint8_t>, but is often fed data from std::strings.
Here's what I was trying to be able to std::move the data from std::string into a std::vector<uint8_t>:
string data = "Some data";
  
vector<uint8_t> utf8( std::make_move_iterator( data.begin() ),
    std::make_move_iterator( data.end() ) );

// Above doesn't actually move the data,  
puts( data.c_str() ); // Not empty!


Any clues how to do that?

No, you cannot move the .data() of a string to a vector.  The API should be changed.

A move iterator on a char is just going to make a copy.  Either start with vectors or pay to have a copy from the string into the vector.

The code moves each element of the string; that won't change the size. And for builtin types like char moving is just copying.

BTW, Title want to move data from a vector, whereas your question is from string... Same answer anyway.

there is no point to move uint8_t this is simple value. Do you control API which "wants" this std::vector? If yes consider change API so it uses std::span from C++20.

Somewhat related: Why std::vector does not have a release method?

Also note that move is NOT required to move data out of the "originating" object at all. The only requirement is that the moved from object is in a valiid but unspecified state (so it can still be destructed). In case of strings you have the short string optimization on top of that. So there isn't even dynamically allocated memory to move around (so the most efficient thing to actually do when moving from a short string... is to do nothing at all)

Technically, yes, but almost definitely not what you mean it to do. You can apply std::move to the result of .data(), however that result doesn't refer to the actual data of the vector - it's just a pointer to the start of it. Moving that pointer means moving the value of the pointer, not the data it refers to.
What you're actually asking if you're able to do - if it's possible to simply move the memory backing the vector and start treating it like a string - isn't possible. At least not explicitly by the standard. In C++23 std::basic_string is gaining the ability to construct a string from an arbitrary range, and an implementation may well decide to add a specialisation that reuses the memory if a moved vector is passed as the range (assuming it can - see below), but you can't explicitly ask for it.
The reason for this is because std::vector and std::string have different invariants. At first glance they both seem similar, they both reference a fixed buffer of memory, of which only a subset of that memory actually has initialised values in it. However, looking deeper std::string has an additional invariant that it needs to keep - if you call .data() on the string, the first size() elements will be the same as the vector, but the element after the last one also needs to be a null-terminator (0). If you were to pass a vector that was filled completely with elements to a string then the string wouldn't be able to place that null terminator at the end because there isn't any space for it. That would mean that doing std::move from a vector to a string would mean that the string might still allocate memory, which is completely the opposite of what you might expect from looking at the code.
There's also the issue that the way std::string and std::vector work might not even be the same with regards to how they manage memory. Before they moved to SSO strings, GCC's implementation of std::string would allocate a size and a reference count in the memory it allocated, and then whenever you copied a string it would increment the reference count but otherwise point to the same memory, and only allocate new memory if you actually modified the string. In that case, the memory layout for the memory allocated by std::string and std::vector would be completely incompatible, since std::vector would have it's chars start right at the start of the allocated memory, but std::string would have them start a small distance after, beyond the size and the reference count.
